# How to use 'in' operator in 'or' filter in Fetchxml based report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am using following xml in an Fetch based report in SSRS for Dynamics 365. I've allowed `@transaction` parameter to null but rest of the both parameters must have values. So, I put an or condition so that if `@transaction` is null or 0 then on the base of 1 and 2 grab the orders. I've total 10 records but they are not being shown or the report preivew show 0 records. Any idea how to resolve this?

```xml
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
      <entity name="salesorder">
        <attribute name="salesorderid" />
        <attribute name="ordernumber" />
        <order attribute="ordernumber" descending="true" />
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="new_transaction" operator="eq" value="@transaction" />
          <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="@To" />
          <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@From" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="or">
            <condition attribute="new_transaction" operator="in" >
                <value>1</value>
                <value>2</value>
            </condition>
          </filter>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can replace your filter like below to get result.

```xml
<filter type="and">
   <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="@To" />
   <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@From" />
   <filter type="or">    
        <condition attribute="new_transaction" operator="in" >
            <value>1</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </condition>
        <condition attribute="new_transaction" operator="eq" value="@transaction" />
   </filter>
</filter>
```

Pro tips:
1.Build the query in Advanced find, test the result & Download fetchxml from there to use in report.

2.If you write SQL query, transform it to fetchxml using Kingswaysoft sql2fetchxml free online converter.

3.Read this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/generate-fetchxml-condition-crm-advanced-find-using-query-kumar) to transform fetchxml into Adv find query.

Comment: 'From' and 'to' both are required parameters and they cannot be empty. So, form your query I think, I would put 'From' and 'To' parameters after 'and' filter as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<filter type="or">
  <condition attribute="new_transaction" operator="in" value=@parm>
  </condition>
</filter>
```

*work for multiple values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).